# offsetTop,offsetLeft and getBoundingClientRect() are not working in my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in react and I'm creating a button with a tooltip, but I can't place it. I mean I can't read the button's distance from the top and left.

I tried offsetTop and offsetLeft and I got this error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined"** so I tried getBoundingClientRect() and all I got is another error: **"Uncaught TypeError: elem.getBoundingClientRect is not a function"**.

I'm passing the information from component to the second component by assigning the distances to the global variable and read it in this second component when I need to place it.

This is my code(on stage when I'm trying to do sth with getBoundingClientRect):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Style from 'style-it'; 
var Ink = require('react-ink');
import FontIcon from '../FontIcon/FontIcon';

var options;

var Tooltip = React.createClass({
  render(){

    var _props = this.props,
      style = {
          top: options.y,
          left: options.x,
      };

    return(
      <div className="tooltip" style={style}>{_props.text}</div>
    );
  }
});

var IconButton = React.createClass({ 

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          iconStyle: "",
          style: "",
          cursorPos: {},
      };
  },

  extend(obj, src) {
      Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
      return obj;
  },

  render() {

    var _props = this.props,
      opts = {},
      disabled = false,
      rippleOpacity,
        outterStyleMy = {
        border: "none",
            outline: "none",
            padding: "8px 10px",
        "background-color": "red",
        "border-radius": 100 + "%",
        cursor: "pointer",
        },
        iconStyleMy = {
            "font-size": 12 + "px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "text-align": "center",
            display: 'flex',
            'justify-content': 'center',
            'align-items': 'center',
        },
      rippleStyle = {
        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
      };

    if (_props.disabled || _props.disableTouchRipple) {
      rippleStyle.opacity = 0;
    };

    this.setState({
      iconStyle: _props.iconStyle
    });

    this.setState({
      style: _props.style
    });

    if (_props.disabled) {
       disabled = true;
    };

    if (this.state.labelStyle) {
        iconStyleMy = this.state.iconStyle;
    };

    if (this.state.style) {
      outterStyleMy = this.state.style;
    };

    if (_props.href) {
      opts.href = _props.href;
    };

    function showTooltip(elem){
      // Here I tried to use offset methods, it's how it looked like:
      // options = {
      //   w: this.refs.button.offsetWidth,
      //   x: this.refs.button.offsetLeft,
      //   y: this.refs.button.offsetTop
      // };

      var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
      options = {
        x: rect.left,
        y: rect.top
      };

    };

    function removeTooltip(elem){
      options = null;
    };

        var buttonStyle = this.extend(outterStyleMy, iconStyleMy);

        return(
        <Style>
        {`
          .IconButton{
            position: relative;
          }
          .IconButton:disabled{
            color: ${_props.disabledColor};
          }
          .btnhref{
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        `}
         <a {...opts} className="btnhref" > 
          <Tooltip text={_props.tooltip} position={this.options} />
          <button ref="button" className={"IconButton" + _props.className} disabled={disabled} style={buttonStyle}
          onMouseEnter={showTooltip(this)} onMouseLeave={removeTooltip(this)} >
            <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
            <FontIcon className={_props.iconClassName}/>
          </button>
        </a>
        </Style>
        );

  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <IconButton href="" className="" iconStyle="" style="" iconClassName="face" disabled="" disableTouchRipple="" tooltip="aaaaa" />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And I have no idea what's wrong :/ Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
functions showTooltip(elem) and removeTooltip(elem)
```

should be outside render() method and bound to IconButton context. Otherwise, `this.refs` will be undefined.

```
<button ref="button" 
className={"IconButton" + _props.className} 
disabled={disabled} 
style={buttonStyle}
onMouseEnter={this.showTooltip.bind(this)} 
onMouseLeave={this.removeTooltip.bind(this)} >
```

alse, i think showTooltip and removeTooltip functions are wrong. They should takes the event as argument, eg::

```
function showTooltip(event){
  var elem = event.target
  var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  options = {
    x: rect.left,
    y: rect.top
  };

};
```

> But now I'm getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'y' of undefined". Meybe there is something wrong with
>   process of passing informations?

You get this error becasuse of this construction:

```
render(){
   var _props = this.props,
         style = {
            top: options.y,
            left: options.x,
         };

         return(
            <div className="tooltip" style={style}>{_props.text}</div>
         );
  }
```

Even if you declare something like `var options` you still have no guarantee that options will be defined and accessible in Tooltip render method.

In general - your code is bad. I strongly suggest you to take some react tutorials, learn about state, props and react component lifecycle. ES6 knowledge won't hurt as well.

Comment: But now I'm getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined". Meybe there is something wrong with process of passing informations?

Comment: How did you solve it @Karol ?